# Should I apt autoremove if it will remove dkms?

Tags: apt, package-management

I had installed the `nvidia-drivers-390`, but then I decided I don't need them, so I uninstalled them again. Now I was installing some other package, and apt displayed a ton of unneeded packages that could be `apt autoremove`d:

```sh
  dctrl-tools dkms
  libatomic1:i386 libbsd0:i386 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386
  libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386
  libedit2:i386 libelf1:i386 libexpat1:i386 libffi7:i386 libgl1:i386
  libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386 libglvnd0:i386 libglx-mesa0:i386
  libglx0:i386 libllvm12:i386 libnvidia-compute-390:i386
  libnvidia-decode-390:i386 libnvidia-encode-390:i386 libnvidia-fbc1-390:i386
  libpciaccess0:i386 libsensors5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libvulkan1:i386
  libwayland-client0:i386 libx11-6:i386 libx11-xcb1:i386 libxau6:i386
  libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-present0:i386
  libxcb-randr0:i386 libxcb-shm0:i386 libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb-xfixes0:i386
  libxcb1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386 libxshmfence1:i386
  libxxf86vm1:i386 mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386
  screen-resolution-extra
```

Whyever should it want  to remove dkms ? And can I safely remove the `:i386` packages when I have an AMD64 processor ?

Comment: Generally speaking I have found autoremove to be safe - it if supposed to be removing package which were added as dependencies to something else (probably the nvidia drivers in your case).  But then again, I have a robust backup, and am not shy about reinstalling everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `dkms` is in the 'main' pocket of the Ubuntu repos, it's not included in a stock install of Ubuntu. It's likely that you added it as a dependency of some other package later.

You are now removing the last packages that depend upon `dkms`, so there is no longer any need for it. Were there any packages installed that require `dkms`, apt would not remove it.

If, in the future, you intall a package that depends upon `dkms`, apt will install it again. Alternately, if it makes you happier, you can simply tell apt to install it.